# AngularUI loading modal template from direct path in ASP.NET.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

From here you can see that you can load html fragments from ASP.NET.MVC controller, which returns a view:

[Angular ng-include cshtml page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801780/angular-ng-include-cshtml-page)

```
<div ng-include="'Home/Template/login'"></div>
```

I tried doing the same with AngularUI modal window :

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "'Home/Template/Modal'"
    });
```

Getting error :

```
GET http://localhost:3289/'Home/Template/Modal' 404 (Not Found)
```

So it is including the quotes in the path, any suggestions how to load HTML fragments from MVC View folder?

Comment: Is the path to your template correct? What do you get if pass it in the browser? Also try to remove the quotes from the path.

Comment: It is the path to my mvc controller, which returns a view file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `templateUrl` property of the `$modal` service doesn't behave the same as `ng-include` (not sure why you've assumed this) in the sense that it is not AngularJS expression but rather a simple JavaScript expression. As such it doesn't need double-quoting to refer to a fixed JavaScript string.

Just write:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'Home/Template/Modal'
});
```