# ng-include cannot locate partial html files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to implement a basic tabset with each tab getting its content from a separate partial view with it's own controller. I have created three dummy HTML files with basic text only just to test the pipes but I can't seem to get ng-include working. I'm not sure how to use it regarding paths. My HTML files are in /Areas/SEFlex/Views/Home/, my angular controllers are in /app/SEFlex/controllers

This is my tab HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <tabset>
                <tab heading="Jobs" ng-show="AuthService.canRunFlexJobs || AuthService.canRunHighPriorityFlexJobs">
                    <div ng-include="'SEFlex/Home/Jobs.cshtml''"></div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Models" ng-show="AuthService.canViewFlexModels">
                    <div>test</div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Administrator" ng-show="AuthService.canAdministerFlex">
                    <div ng-include="'SEFlex/Home/Administrator.cshtml''"></div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
        </div>
```

Have I got the relative paths wrong?

Comment: No error messages in console, no. Is it right to be pointing to the cshtml files or should I really be pointing to an MVC Controller method that returns a View?

Comment: You can return static html files, create a folder outside the main `views` folder ie `static->views` and place your html files in there, or see here for what you are mentioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801780/angular-ng-include-cshtml-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a syntax error with an extra single quote.

```
<div ng-include="'SEFlex/Home/Jobs.cshtml'"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It says src is unknown attribute of DIV

Comment: My bad. Updating my answer. Still too early in the morning here!

Comment: Most examples use something like  <div ng-include="'views/main.html'"></div> - but where would that "views" folder be in your structure?

Comment: That views folder would be inside of the folder that the view being rendered currently is in with the relative path defined.

Comment: So if the view I'm trying to include is in the same folder, I should just be able to put <div ng-include="'Jobs.cshtml'"></div>? Is it the same for .cshtml Razor view files or can I only include pure html this way?

Comment: That is correct about the relative path. Not sure about Razor views as I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    switch (id.ToLower())
    {
        case "index":
            return View();
        case "search":
            return PartialView("~/Views/App/SearchResults.cshtml");
        default:
            throw new Exception("template not known");
    }
    //return View();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<md-tab label="Search and Results">
    <div ng-include="'Home/Index/search'"></div>
</md-tab> <br>
```